# Await for a callback to be called

Tags: rust

I'm using the [headless_chrome](https://crates.io/crates/headless_chrome) Rust crate to screenshot a webpage. I want to wait until the page is loaded (including it's assets such as CSS and fonts) before taking the screenshot.

According to the [docs](https://docs.rs/headless_chrome/1.0.8/headless_chrome/browser/tab/struct.Tab.html#method.add_event_listener), you can add an event listener that looks something like the following snippet:

```rust
tab.add_event_listener(Arc::new(move |event: &Event| {
    if let Event::PageLoadEventFired(_) = event {
        println!("Page loaded");
    }
}))?;
```

However, I cannot figure out how to pause execution of the Rust program until the page is loaded because I can't figure out how to convert this callback into an awaitable expression.

```rust
tab.add_event_listener(Arc::new(move |event: &Event| {
    if let Event::PageLoadEventFired(_) = event {
        println!("Page loaded");
    }
}))?;

// only run code here once the page is loaded
```

### JS version

The equivalent JavaScript solution is something like the following:

```js
const waitForPageLoad = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        window.addEventListener("load", resolve)
    })
}

await waitForPageLoad()
```

Comment: It seems that you've answered the question, b/c `println!("Page loaded")` is executed when it's loaded, so you can do the screenshot. But if you want to do it outside, you can use something like `tokio::sync::Notify` to send a notification between tasks

Comment: hint: https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/sync/oneshot/index.html

Answer (score 2):

In this context, the closest equivalent of a raw `Promise` is a oneshot channel.

The result would look like:

```rust
let (tx, rx) = tokio::sync::oneshot::channel();
tab.add_event_listener(Arc::new(move |event: &Event| {
    if let Event::PageLoadEventFired(_) = event {
        tx.send(()); // You could send something more interesting instead of `()`.
    }
}))?;


rx.await.unwrap();

// This code will be executed after the page is loaded.
```